# output file from outlook to folder then to specified printer using powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, outlook

```
$OutputFolder = 'C:\tests';

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application; 
$olFolderInbox = 6;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
$inbox.Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'colour' `
    | % Items `
    | % Attachments `
    | % {
        $OutputFileName = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $_.FileName;
        if (Test-Path $OutputFileName) {
            $FileDirectoryName = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($OutputFileName);
            $FileNameWithoutExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($OutputFileName);
            $FileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($OutputFileName);

            for ($i = 2; Test-Path $OutputFileName; $i++) {
                $OutputFileName = "{0} ({1}){2}" -f (Join-Path -Path $FileDirectoryName -ChildPath $FileNameWithoutExtension), $i, $FileExtension;
            }
        }
        Write-Host $OutputFileName;
        $_.SaveAsFile($OutputFileName)
    }`enter code here`
```

This works perfectly, although i am attempting to output the files by inserting the code:

```
Foreach-Object { Start-Process -FilePath $_.FullName –Verb Print } -verbose
```

Can anyone tell me where i would insert it above, the saveasfile doesnt return objects to the pipeline. Is there also any scope to utilise powershell to specify a certain printer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide which specific version of PowerShell you're using?  I believe there are some more recent cmdlets in newer PowerShell versions that could be easier for you, if you're running that version.  (Do `$PSVersionTable` in PowerShell, and provide us with that value returned for `PSVersion`)